# Start selling without registering the trademark

Tags: trademark

I've been reading a bit about trademarks, and I sort of understood that, if someone register the mark, but I was using it already, then I won't be infringing. So if my business is not going to rely a lot on the mark like, say, Coca Cola, because, for example, I am simply exploiting a patent, is there any reason for registering the mark?

Or could I simply check that what I choose isn't already registered in the same category, and then just go ahead and use it? If the answer is yes, where can i check what categories is a trademark registered for? I checked USPTO and WIPO, but couldn't see categories..

Comment: Trademark law varies somewhat in different jurisdictions. What country would you be selling in?

Comment: I'd be interested mostly in US, EU and JP